# Stop allowing random.range to pick up the same spawnpoint. it causes the enemies to overlap over each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i have a enemy spawn system and its working fine. however the enemies are overlapping on same point because i am using random.range, I have 4 points on the map and i want each enemy to pick a point randomly. Therefore i want after spawning the enemy the other enemy gets only 3 options to spawn at and not 4.

Here is my Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour {

    // The enemy prefab to be spawned.
    public GameObject[] enemy;  

    //public Transform[] spawnPoints;         
    public List<Transform> spawnPoints = new List<Transform>();
    private float timer = 3;

    int index = 0;    
    List <GameObject> EnemiesList = new List<GameObject>();
    private int m_enemyCount = 4;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (timer >0)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (timer <= 0 )
        {               
            if ( EnemiesList.Count == 0 )
            {
                Spawner();  
                timer = 5;
            }
        }
    }

    void Spawner ()
    {
        // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position.
        //Create the enemies at a random transform 
        for (int i = 0; i<m_enemyCount;i++)
        {
            int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Count);
            Transform pos = spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex];

            GameObject InstanceEnemies= Instantiate ( enemy[index] , spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position , Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            // Create enemies and add them to our list.
            EnemiesList.Add(InstanceEnemies);               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the already taken spawnpoints from the list `spawnPoints` at the end of the for-loop like this:

```
spawnPoints.RemoveAt(spawnPointIndex);
```

You might want to create a copy of that list before the for-loop though to keep the original as is.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to handle this is to make a local list of spawn points in your `Spawner()` method, so you can keep track of which spawn points you have already used.  For example:

```
void Spawner ()
{
    //create a local list of spawn points
    List<Transform> availablePoints = new List<Transform>(spawnPoints);

    // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position.
    //Create the enemies at a random transform 
    for (int i = 0; i<m_enemyCount;i++)
    {
        //use local availableSpawnPoints instead of your global spawnPoints to generate spawn index
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, availableSpawnPoints.Count);
        Transform pos = spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex];

        GameObject InstanceEnemies= Instantiate ( enemy[index] , avaialableSpawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position , Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        // Create enemies and add them to our list.
        EnemiesList.Add(InstanceEnemies);

       //remove the used spawnpoint
       availableSpawnPoints.RemoveAt(spawnPointIndex);

    }
}
```

This solution ensures that your global list of spawn points will remain intact for the next time you call the `Spawner()` method.

Comment: oh but now when my enemies die i get this error Argument is out of range.

Comment: woops, my mistake! see my updated answer. I forgot to new up a list in the Spawner() method instead of directly copying spawnPoints.  This should solve your issue

Comment: by adding the updates the enemies again overlap on top of each other D:

Comment: Looks like the instantiate was using the global spawnPoints instead of availableSpawnPoints.  I have updated the answer, hopefully for the last time! :D

Comment: Corrects :) u rock :D